# Casting to an interface the object did not inhereit

Tags: java, templates, inheritance, casting

## Real World Example

Bats, birds, dragonflys, and humans all are able to fly, but have evolved the ability to do it independently through [convergent evolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergent_evolution).

## Applied to Java

`Bat`, `Bird`, `Dragonfly`, and `Human` all implement the `.fly()` function, but do not inherit it from a common class. I need a function that takes in an `Organism`, not knowing if is a `Bat`, `Bird`, `Dragonfly`, or `Human` but knowing it has the `.fly()` function.

## Current Solution

```
public flyBaby(Bat organism){
 organism.fly();
}
public flyBaby(Dragonfly organism){
 organism.fly();
}
public flyBaby(Bird organism){
 organism.fly();
}
public flyBaby(Human organism){
 organism.fly();
}
```

## Broken Attempts

```
public <T> void flyBaby(T organism){
 organism.fly();
}
public void run(){
 Bat fred = new Bat();
 fred.infect("corona_virus");
 flyBaby(fred);
}
```

or like

```
public void flyBaby(Flyable organism){
 organism.fly();
}
public void run(){
 Bat fred = new Bat();
 fred.infect("corona_virus");
 flyBaby((Flyable)fred);
}
```

Comment: Biologic evolution and OOP paradigms aren't expected to match in this way. Why are you trying to force something that is a bit untenable? Yes, all 3 types of organisms fly, but their mechanisms for doing so are completely different

Comment: I writing a plugin that has the same function on 3 different objects, `getShape()` but the objects don't inherit a class that implements `getShape()`

Comment: Obviously they should all implement an interface, like `FlightCapable`.  If they don’t, what you’re looking for is “duck typing,” which does not exist in Java.  You can’t implement an interface just by imitating it.  You *could* use reflection, but you really really shouldn’t.

Comment: You can do some [rudimentary duck-typing](https://github.com/BeUndead/duck) in java.  Writing your own `Flying` interface and duck-typing them to that should work. (Disclaimer, I wrote that, but more as a proof of concept...  No claim of it being great or anything.)

Comment: You could also make your plugin method accept a `Supplier<Shape>` or any other such interface, and call it with `doThing(this::getShape);`.

Comment: Ugh, you stated that the objects did not inherit from an interface

Answer (score 0):

As VGR said in the comment, you would have to

1. write an interface (Flyable);
2. make your classes implement it;
3. write a class (FlyClass) with the static method fly(Flyable f) implemented in it; and
4. and make a call to fly in main(): FlyClass.fly(new Human() | new Bat | etc.).

Making an interface and implementing the same method in each class would be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

The mechanism to declare common methods without inheritance is called an Interface.
Interfaces are special types of class definitions that (usually) only contain method definitions.

Your attempt using a "Flyable" type should work as long

- Flyable is an interface
- all organism classes "implement" that interface

Something like

```
public interface Flyable {
    public void fly();
}
public class Bat implements Flyable {
    ...
}

public void flyBaby(Flyable organism){
 organism.fly();
}
public void run(){
 Bat fred = new Bat();
 flyBaby(fred);
}
```